# How to make pull up effect during hovering element? Just see this code once

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to create an effect when **div class="container"** is being hovered, a smooth upper transition occurs of another div from bottom. Only during hover, this should happen cause I want that **.bottom div** to be hidden. When that div is not hidden, I can see the effect as I want. But as I hide the bottom div, that hovering effect smooth transition effect cannot be seen. Check this code once.

```
HTML CODE
<div class="box">
 Hello
  <div class="bottom">
    Everyone
  </div>
</div>
```

```
CSS code
.box{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.bottom {
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:0;
 /* display: none; */
 
  
}
.box:hover .bottom {
  display: block;
  transition: linear 0.2s;
  top:55px; 
}
```

Here is the codepen link
https://codepen.io/Biebk/pen/MWpREqb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, rather than `display: none` to hide the incoming element altogether, you can set its `opacity` to `0`, and then when the parent is hovered, set it to `1`, like so:

```
.bottom {
  opacity: 0;
}
.box:hover .bottom {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I suppose that given you want an incoming "pull-up" effect on hover, you want to that element to also "pull-down" when the hover ends. You can reverse the same effect by using a `:not(:hover)` on the parent element:

```
.box:not(:hover) .bottom {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Also, be sure to set the `transition` on the non-hovered state. The following example provides the smooth transition you're looking for:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.box:not(:hover) .bottom {
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box:hover .bottom {
  top: 55px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Hello
  <div class="bottom">
    Everyone
  </div>
</div>
```

A secondary approach would be to place the `bottom` div as a sibling to the `box`, and use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to apply the hover effects:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.box:hover + .bottom {
  top: 55px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 Hello
</div>
<div class="bottom">
  Everyone
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.hovered{
  transition: all .2s;
}
.bottom {
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hovered:hover+.bottom {
   transition: all .2s;
  top: 55px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="hovered">Hello</div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Everyone
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is where I have already reached. You stopped at the same place where I am stuck. May be, I am not able to properly make you understand, but, what i trying to do is, this div containing "everyone" should be  hidden. That transition that you showed me us okay, but that should happen when "hello" is hovered. But see "everyone" is still visible. I tried to use `display: none` in your code as well. But still the same as mine. Thanks though for effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use **opacity** property rather than display to achieve the desired effect, then
use the following code

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bottom {
  background: pink;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.box:hover .bottom{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s , top 1s;
  top: 55px;
}
```

Comment: But see, when I take my pointer across that invisible area, my pointer is changing. It's kinda of ugly don't you think. All I wanted a pull up hover effect and that is solved. But here arose a new problem. What do you think about it? Don't you think it is kinda making  not that good impression.

Comment: @Biebk check my answer below, the cursor issue (at least the one I think you are referring to), is not happening with that solution

Comment: @MAR yeah, I was reviewing your code. Actually, you went ahead of what I was seeking and also gave a nice pull down effect when being not hovered. That's incredible for me to learn. But, I can still see the same problem I faced with Aryaman code in your code as well. But I got what was causing that problem. Check your code once, see everything is great, except when you hover over the opacity: 0 element that we have hidden. That hover effect is occurring. Just hover over the hidden element and you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: @MAR The reason that is happening because we have contained the .bottom class div inside of .box class div. Now we have applied hover on box class, that means the element inside of .box are also prone to hover. What we can do is create a container div holding our box and bottom div and apply hover to .box . Now this will work. Correct me if I am wrong about this.

Comment: @MAR I just found there is no need to use that :not(:hover) effect. I is automatically happening since we have put that transition property in .bottom class itself. Isn't that nice.

Comment: @Biebk, yes you can do it this way as well. I've updated my answer accordingly. Note that I've added `cursor: default;` to avoid the text-cursor appearing when the hidden element is hovered.